# Whats my IP and subnet from Azure website?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, networking, azure

Im building out an Azure hosted website, but it needs to reach into our home office to connect to some internally hosted web services.  Our firewall is setup to only allow traffic over certain IP's, so we're looking to determine what IP range we need to allow access to.

Currently I'm still using the MSDN "Free" Azure subscription, so I don't know what options may be limited, but is there a way I can determine what source IP, subnet, whatever my Azure hosted site will attempt to call my web services from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you're looking for:

[Windows Azure Datacenter IP Ranges](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/08/14/windows-azure-datacenter-ip-ranges.aspx#.UhOML5LFVy4)

Comment: Also keep in mind the specific IP you have for your web site is not fixed. if its a PaaS/IaaS service, there's some steps you can tell to help keep it quasi-stable, but there's no option to "reserve" an IP address currently.

Comment: Thanks so much @Chris, exactly what I needed.  Duly noted Brent, appreciate that insight as well

Answer (score 1):

Be careful opening your firewall to the entire Azure datacenter IP ranges.  Anybody can host anything in Azure, including malicious software, so if you open your firewall to the entire Azure IP range you may as well just open to 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 because in effect you are getting the same security.

A better option is to deploy your service and just whitelist that one IP address.  That IP address is guaranteed to remain the same until you delete your service.  With the ability to do in-place upgrades and VIP swaps there should be no reason why you would need to delete your hosted service and lose your IP address.  If you ever do run into a scenario where you need to delete/redeploy you can always update your firewall at that time.

Comment: Its not the service, its the deployment. I would also strongly caution against referring to this as "guaranteed". Under normal circumstances, it should remain stable, if something extraordinary were to happen, its still possible (however unlikely) that the IP address may change.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification Brent, I should have said deployment and not service.  But the IP address is guaranteed to remain stable - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/07/06/windows-azure-deployments-and-the-virtual-ip-address.aspx.

Comment: With all respect to Corey, a blog post does not a binding contract make. I maintain that there is no guarantee. Even the datacenter IP list states that ranges are subject to change without notification.